# BIND v9.9.7, Views and includes

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind

I have recently begun upgrading to bind 9.9.7 and have run into an unfortunate stumbling block with bind.

I setup views in my environment to allow me to differentiate 4 of my zones with different IP addresses based on where the host is running a query from. The other 36 zones I serve do not differentiate IP addresses, but rather should always serve out the same address for each host. To accomplish this, I created a separate list of hosts which then I used an `include` directive in the `named.conf` to include those entries in both zones. Here's a short example of the configuration I have been running with on one of my slave servers:

First, a snippet of my named.conf

```
view "sitea" {
   match-clients {192.168.1.0/24;};
   zone "mydomain.com." IN {
      type slave;
      masters { 192.168.1.100;};
      file "sitea_mydomain.com.db";
   };
   include "/etc/common_zones.conf";
};

view "siteb" {
   match-clients {any; };
   zone "mydomain.com." IN {
      type slave;
      masters {192.168.1.100; };
      file "mydomain.com.db";
   };
   include "/etc/common_zones.conf";
};
```

And a snippet from the `common_zones.conf` file:

```
zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa." IN {
   type slave;
   masters {192.168.1.100;};
   file "192.168.1.db";
};
```

In the time before, bind was perfectly cool with using the same file twice within the view construct, but now it is not. Having a zone file listed twice in two different views causes an error that specifically tells you that bind will not allow this configuration. In this case it tells me it will not start because I have used a duplicate file `192.168.1.db`. Specifically the error message is:

```
writeable file '192.168.1.db': already in use: /etc/common_zones.conf
```

The problem I have with this is in my real world, I have over 40 zones (reverse zones) that despite the view they come from, they will always be the same answer no matter what. Being able to use a general include as shown above was a wonderful way to allow me to differentiate a few hosts for the domain "`mydomain.com`". Now, I am faced with possibly needing to have to enter in 40 zones in each view, each pointing to a different file despite the fact that the data is identical.

Does anyone have a clever solution for this?

Comment: This appears to be dynamic DNS related, as with `allow-update { none; };` BIND 9.9.7-P2 is cool with this `include` style, but not if I instead put in an `update-policy` configuration for the thus shared zones.

Comment: That's what I had thought too, but even explicitly telling it not to allow updates, it still refuses to run with that configuration. I understand the issue, in that two slave zones sharing the same file that get updates from the master - I get the conflict, but darn it, this used to work.

Comment: Hmm. That be a right square pickle you've got there. Hacks and kluges only come to mind, such as running two different servers, or such?

Comment: @EirikToft It didn't refuse this type of misconfiguration, but it didn't work properly to set it up that way. I think that is actually an important distinction.

Comment: Can you symlink the files so that they look different to the parser?

Answer (score 3):

If upgrading to Bind 9.10 is a possibility, the "in-view" statement would solve this perfectly ( http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/zone.html#in-view ).

However, if that's not possible, I noticed something quite interesting that I did not know while looking up "in-view".  For slave zones, the "file" parameter (it happens to immediately precede "in-view" in the above link) is *optional*.  This might be just the solution you're looking for.  I'm assuming the zone would exist only in RAM and get retransferred every time the slave restarted or reloaded the zone.  It's worth a shot. (Edit: You'd still need 2 versions of your common file, one for masters with file names, and one without - so this isn't quite a perfect solution)

Comment: That's a great suggestion. I did try that, but as you well stated, it still requires I keep two separate copies of the shared common file. This is the one thing I have been trying to avoid having to do. The big issue is that my older version of Bind should not have allowed me to do what I'm doing now - but it did, and now I'm spoiled. :)

Comment: @EirikToft Does that mean that proper operation is secondary to the desire to reuse the exact same zone definitions? (That seems to be the implication of having been spoiled by something that didn't really work right.)

Comment: After re-reading everything, I'm not certain there's any more maintenance that would be required.  It appears that your common file is only tailored for the slaves anyway ("type slave;" in the zones).  . . .  And welcome to BIND, please leave hopes of upward compatibility at the door! LOL

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps with a `named.conf` configuration of:

```
view "sitea" {
  include "/etc/common_zones.conf";
  match-clients {localhost; ...; };
};
view "siteb" {
  include "/etc/UNcommon_zones.conf";
  match-clients {any;};
};
```

And then `common_zones.conf` is what it currently is, while over in `UNcommon_zones.conf` you put in forwarders:

```
zone "..." IN {
  type forward;
  forward only;
  forwarders { 127.0.0.1; };
};
```

which at least does not error out in quite limited testing with a test virt pulling a master zone and another test virt issuing queries to said test slave NS.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. The one thing I have been trying to accomplish is to not have to create multiple "shared" zone configurations - and rather be able to share the same one between views.

Comment: Forwarding will only work for recursion requests (queries with `RD` set), meaning it's entirely dependent on the specific scenario if this approach works at all. Then there's the inefficiency of forwarding, for the scenario where it does work.